# Align numbers in sublist

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, numbers, alignment

I have a set of numbers that I want to align considering the comma:

```
   10    3          
  200    4000,222  3  1,5 
  200,21          0,3  2   
30000    4,5      1      

mylist = [['10', '3', '', ''], 
          ['200', '4000,222', '3', '1,5'], 
          ['200,21', '', '0,3', '2'], 
          ['30000', '4,5', '1', '']]
```

What I want is to align this list considering the comma:

expected result:

```
mylist = [['   10   ', '   3    ', '   ', '   '], 
          ['  200   ', '4000,222', '3  ', '1,5'], 
          ['  200,21', '        ', '0,3', '2  '], 
          ['30000   ', '   4,5  ', '1  ', '   ']]
```

I tried to turn the list:

```
mynewlist = list(zip(*mylist))
```

and to find the longest part after the comma in every sublist:

```
for m in mynewlist:
    max([x[::-1].find(',') for x in m]
```

and to use rjust and ljust but I don't know how to ljust after a comma and rjust before the comma, both in the same string.

How can I resolve this without using format()?
(I want to align with ljust and rjust)

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard, sure str.center would be ok. However aligning center doesn't have the results as above.

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard why did you delete your answer? looked good. I hope it's just temporary. about `sum(,[])`: I found that amusing to use but the problem is that it does `a = a+b` instead of `a+=b` each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another approach that currently does the trick. Unfortunately, I can't see any simple way to make this work, maybe due to the time :-)

Either way, I'll explain it. `r` is the result list created before hand.

```
r = [[] for i in range(4)]
```

Then we loop through the values and also grab an index with `enumerate`:

```
for ind1, vals in enumerate(zip(*mylist)):
```

Inside the loop we grab the max length of the decimal digits present and the max length of the word (the word w/o the decimal digits):

```
    l = max(len(v.partition(',')[2]) for v in vals) + 1
    mw = max(len(v if ',' not in v else v.split(',')[0]) for v in vals)
```

Now we go through the values inside the tuple `vals` and build our results (yup, can't currently think of a way to avoid this nesting).

```
    for ind2, v in enumerate(vals):
```

If it contains a comma, it should be formatted differently. Specifically, we `rjust` it based on the max length of a word `mw` and then add the decimal digits and any white-space needed:

```
        if ',' in v:
            n, d = v.split(',')
            v = "".join((n.rjust(mw),',', d, " " * (l - 1 - len(d))))
```

In the opposite case, we simply `.rjust` and then add whitespace:

```
        else:
            v = "".join((v.rjust(mw) + " " * l))
```

finally, we `append` to `r`.

```
        r[ind1].append(v)
```

All together:

```
r = [[] for i in range(4)]
for ind1, vals in enumerate(zip(*mylist)):
    l = max(len(v.partition(',')[2]) for v in vals) + 1
    mw = max(len(v if ',' not in v else v.split(',')[0]) for v in vals)
    for ind2, v in enumerate(vals):
        if ',' in v:
            n, d = v.split(',')
            v = "".join((n.rjust(mw),',', d, " " * (l - 1 - len(d))))
        else:
            v = "".join((v.rjust(mw) + " " * l))
        r[ind1].append(v)
```

Now, we can print it out:

```
>>> print(*map(list,zip(*r)), sep='\n)
['   10   ', '   3    ', '   ', '   ']
['  200   ', '4000,222', '3  ', '1,5']
['  200,21', '        ', '0,3', '2  ']
['30000   ', '   4,5  ', '1  ', '   ']
```

Comment: good, but the way to compute max string length is inefficient: `sum` on lists is not very good (better use `itertools.chain`) and you don't have to create a new list for that just do `l = max(len(x) for l in mylist for x in l)`

Comment: `chain` would be best indeed. I went with your second suggestion here to not import things. I always come up with `sum(..,[])` in cases like this for some reason, it appeals to me :-)

Answer (score 1):

This works for python 2 and 3. I didn't use ljust or rjust though, i just added as many spaces before and after the number as are missing to the maximum sized number in the column:

```
mylist = [['10', '3', '', ''], 
          ['200', '4000,222', '3', '1,5'], 
          ['200,21', '', '0,3', '2'], 
          ['30000', '4,5', '1', '']]
transposed = list(zip(*mylist))
sizes = [[(x.index(",") if "," in x else len(x), len(x) - x.index(",") if "," in x else 0)
  for x in l] for l in transposed]
maxima = [(max([x[0] for x in l]), max([x[1] for x in l])) for l in sizes]
withspaces = [
  [' ' * (maxima[i][0] - sizes[i][j][0]) + number + ' ' * (maxima[i][1] - sizes[i][j][1])
  for j, number in enumerate(l)] for i, l in enumerate(transposed)]
result = list(zip(*withspaces))
```

Printing the result in python3:

```
>>> print(*result, sep='\n')                             
('   10   ', '   3    ', '   ', '   ')
('  200   ', '4000,222', '3  ', '1,5')
('  200,21', '        ', '0,3', '2  ')
('30000   ', '   4,5  ', '1  ', '   ')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bit different solution that doesn't transpose `my_list` but instead iterates over it twice. On the first pass it generates a list of tuples, one for each column. Each tuple is a pair of numbers where first number is length before comma and second number is length of comma & everything following it. For example `'4000,222'` results to `(4, 4)`. On the second pass it formats the data based on the formatting info generated on first pass.

```
from functools import reduce

mylist = [['10', '3', '', ''],
          ['200', '4000,222', '3', '1,5'], 
          ['200,21', '', '0,3', '2'], 
          ['30000', '4,5', '1', '']]

# Return tuple (left part length, right part length) for given string
def part_lengths(s):
    left, sep, right = s.partition(',')
    return len(left), len(sep) + len(right)

# Return string formatted based on part lengths
def format(s, first, second):
    left, sep, right = s.partition(',')
    return left.rjust(first) + sep + right.ljust(second - len(sep))

# Generator yielding part lengths row by row
parts = ((part_lengths(c) for c in r) for r in mylist)

# Combine part lengths to find maximum for each column
# For example data it looks like this: [[5, 3], [4, 4], [1, 2], [1, 2]]
sizes = reduce(lambda x, y: [[max(z) for z in zip(a, b)] for a, b in zip(x, y)], parts)

# Format result based on part lengths
res = [[format(c, *p) for c, p in zip(r, sizes)] for r in mylist]

print(*res, sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
['   10   ', '   3    ', '   ', '   ']
['  200   ', '4000,222', '3  ', '1,5']
['  200,21', '        ', '0,3', '2  ']
['30000   ', '   4,5  ', '1  ', '   ']
```